# Navigation in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to navigate to another page in my Windows Phone 8.1 app.I can easily do this if there is a button by clicking on it and using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` in the `event handler`.But in my case I want to navigate to a second page automatically depending upon an integer value.If it becomes zero,the page automatically goes to second page.In my case I dont have a `button` and so `event handler` so to do this.How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your view model. Here is a crude implementation, ideally, you would use an mvvm framework and send messages to your views as required.

View Model

```
public class GameStateViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int currentScore = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// The timer here added to simulate whatever is supposed to be changing your value. 
    /// </summary>
    public GameStateViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };

        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (this.CurrentScore > 0)
            {
                this.CurrentScore--;
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
        };

        timer.Start();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int CurrentScore
    {
        get { return currentScore; }
        set
        {
            currentScore = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentScore");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Code behind

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new GameStateViewModel();

        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (viewModel.CurrentScore <= 0)
            {
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        };

        this.DataContext = viewModel;

    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentScore}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
    </Grid>
```